# Parse SignUpCallback() method error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to follow the quick start guide at, https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#social/mobile/android/native/existing ,and add a user so I can test it and make sure everything is working. When I get to this part

```
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

I get an error on the new SignUpCallBack() method.It says that I must declare it abstract or implement abstract method done(ParseException) in SignUpCallBack. I have no clue how to fix it. I figured it was that SignUpCallBack had to be imported, but it already was so now I don't know what to do.

Here's the whole activity class it's in.

```
 package interested.social.com.interested;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;

 import com.parse.Parse;
 import com.parse.ParseUser;
 import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

 import java.text.ParseException;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "PjeUs8h1gJqgFgk48ptUUp7QqyyFOXxTYriwjCVu", "0lj44wRi0xHhOmSTtfpAcxyBlZKuzBX23J95wzAL");


    ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
    newUser.setUsername(username);
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            } else {
                // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                // to figure out what went wrong
            }
        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `@Override` decorator right above the `done` method like this otherwise it doesn't know that you are implementing the correct method:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } else {
      // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
      // to figure out what went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Try also `com.parse.ParseException e` instead of `ParseException e` as the parameter to the `done()` method as posted above.  And of course don't forget to assign `setUsername`, `setPassword` and `setEmail` with values.

Comment: I added the @override and it says method does not override method from it's superclass

Comment: can you please post the entire contents of your file?  I don't think this is an issue with your SignUpCallback callback.

Comment: Yes.  Edit your question to include the entire contents of your Activity.java file.

Comment: try using the line I just modified in my answer.  instead of `done(ParseException e)` try `done(com.parse.ParseException e)`

Comment: Thanks! It took the error away. Now when I run it, and click the test button it says not user data yet so I'm going to have to figure out what's going with that.

Comment: You're welcome!  It's probably because you haven't assigned a username, password and email yet before calling .signUpInBackgroun().  Make sure you set those values before you sign them up.  Then you will see that data saved in the User class in the data browser.